# Strange output in Hadoop mapreduce

Tags: java, dictionary, hadoop, reduce, out

This is a sample from the input file:

```
1,name1,name2 
2,name3,name4 
3,name5,name6
```

and this is my map method:

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException 
{
    String line = value.toString();
    StringTokenizer tk = new StringTokenizer( line, ",");       
    String keyValue = tk.nextToken();
    String s1Value = tk.nextToken();
    String s2Value = tk.nextToken();
    String valueString = s1Value+","+s2Value;
    output.collect( new Text(keyValue), new Text(valueString) );
}
```

and this is my reduce function:

```
public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> 
{
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, 
        OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException 
    {
        String item="";
        Text tmp= new Text();
        while ( values.hasNext() ) 
        {
            tmp = values.next();
        }
        item = tmp.toString();

        StringTokenizer tk = new StringTokenizer( item, ",");

        String s1="";
        String s2="";
        boolean entered = false;
        try
        {
            while ( tk.hasMoreTokens() && !entered )
            {   
                s1 = tk.nextToken();
                s2 = tk.nextToken();
                entered = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e )
        {
            System.out.println("PROBLEM:"+item);
        }
        double result = compare(s1,s2);
        String result2 = s1+" & "+s2+"="+result;
        output.collect( key, new Text(result2) );
    }
}
```

So i expect the output to be (e.g.):

```
name1 & name2=1.0
```

But what I get is:

```
name1 & name2=1.0  &  =0.0
```

looks like all the time there are two empty strings get compared!!
Why there are always empty strings?

Comment: What does the counter dump say about number of mapper output records and number of reducer methods?

Comment: it says: 13 for both, since I have 13 lines in the input file, and I want each line to be processed individually..

Answer (score 0):

It should care the code of "compare(s1,s2)";
Please paste the code of compare function.

Comment: the "compare" code is like any code to compare two strings and it returns the edit distance (for example) or how much the two strings are similar in scale between 0-1.